# Display all the longest words in a list in Python

Tags: list, function, for-loop, max, min

I want to display all the words which are the longest in the list. I have used the max function, however the max function only returns the first of the largest string in the list i.e "have". How do I make it print out all the longest elements of the string?

Desirable output : 'have' 'been' 'good'
output obtained  : 'have'

```
def longestWord(input_str):
    input_list = input_str.split()
    return max(input_list, key=len)

longestWord("I have been good")

output: 'have'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code thath compare the len of all items with the max len then append it to another list

```
def longestWord(input_str):
input_list = input_str.split()
lenght = len(max(input_list, key=len))
allMax=[]
for f in input_list:
    if len(f) == lenght:
       allMax.append(f)
       print(f)
return allMax
```

longestWord("I have been good")